# Excel to count cells between specific dates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have daily sales record throughout the year. so column A showing date from 1st Jan to 31st Dec. Column B is having sale amount. Some of the days having zero sale value. 
I want to count number of days with continuous sale as of date.
for example:

```
Date   Sale
Jan1   500
Jan2   800 
Jan3   0
Jan4   200
Jan5   950
Jan6   200
Jan7   300
Jan8   100
Jan9   0
Jan10  250
```

Continuous sale days as of Jan 7 are 4 and as of Jan 4 is 1.

What formula to be put to get these results?

Comment: Do you want the count at every day or do you want the count at specific days?

Comment: Dear, I want to count at every day basis, mean I want to put any date from the data of 365 days to get the count.

Answer (score 1):

In **C1** enter:

**1**

and in **C2** enter:

```
=IF(B2=0,0,C1+1)
```

and copy down.

Comment: +1 Yep, then just do a vlookup referencing the date to get the count (per the comments).

Comment: @Raystafarian  the wording of the  original question needed clarification.

Comment: I agree, but I think your approach is probably the best.

Comment: Thanks Gary's student and Raystafrian, combination of you both has solve my problem. since I want to get the count in one cell so Vlookup is required. However, it need to have another column. is it possible to get without adding another column?

Comment: @Mahnaya It **might** be possible with an *array formula*, but I do not have enough expertise on this type of formula.

Comment: thanks, its fine now. you may solve another problem. I want excel to stop calculation if invalid date is put. I tried to use "data Validation" using below formula =AND(ISNUMBER(E3),LEFT(CELL("format",E3),1)="D"). it is working but the calculation don't stop. since my calculations is having some circular references, that's why the calculated values at invalid date is not reverting back.